# sending a string message through SendMessage API between window application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, window, ipc

Can anyone tell me how to send string messages between two applications.
with the SendMessage API.

i want to send message different-2 beetween two window application running in same machine.

Answer (score 0):

These are api calls so you need to import the dll. the details are explained in details by some good friend in below link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/94e500c8-6d1b-43bf-9c04-9823597525bf/how-to-use-sendmessage-in-c?forum=winforms

Comment: That's not a lot of code.  Best to put the code in your answer to preserve it in case the link becomes invalid.